# how to access iis based local website over internet(worldwide)?

Tags: iis, localhost, lan, web-development-server

My Companies website is running locally through my IP:8081 within my LAN network. I am trying to access this website from a different LAN's computer but it couldn't work so I want to access my website from another LAN PC so how can I do that?

for ex. i am running my website server on computer from LAN1 say its computer-1

Now I have another computer ( computer-2) on LAN2 with different ip address

I want to access the website from computer_2.

Answer (score 0):

If LAN1 and LAN2 are different local area networks, they cannot access each other, they can only be accessed in the same local area network.